# How to dynamically populate checkbox value inside repeater field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm able to populate checkbox value with my custom post "features" in a simple custom field with this code where my field name is "simple_field".

```
function acf_load_features_field_choices( $field ) {

    $field['choices'] = array();

    $features = get_posts(array(
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'features',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ));

    foreach( $features as $feature ) {
        $value = $feature->ID;
        $label = $feature->post_title;

        $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label;
    }

    return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=simple_field', 'acf_load_features_field_choices');
```

But I need to populate a checkbox field that lives on inside a repeater field where my Repeater filed name is "feature_item" and checkbox field name is "list".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Elliot says on this [form](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/dynamically-populate-a-select-subfield-in-a-repeater-field/). Try to use the key of the subfield. [Here you can find how to view the key of the field](https://thestizmedia.com/show-field-keys-acf-pro/)

`add_filter('acf/load_field/key={your key here}', 'acf_load_features_field_choices')`;